# Passing user input data from html to php page and showing the content back to html page without reloading

Tags: php

I have a text box which takes URL as a input from user and on submission I want this URL to pass onto PHP page where I can make use of this URL. After all the processing in the php page, I want to show data on the same html page where user entered the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass variable to php site you need to use one of 2 solutions.

1. Ajax I'd recommend [Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) - this solution passes variable without page reload.
2. The other solution is to use form tag.

Code:

```
<form method="POST" action="test.php">
    <input type="text" value="value of variable" name="testname" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit me" />
</form>
```

This will pass variable via POST method and it can be accessed in **test.php**

`<?php echo $_POST['testname']; ?>`

```
<form method="GET" action="test.php">
   <input type="text" value="value of variable" name="testname" />
   <input type="submit" value="submit me" />
</form>
```

This will pass variable via POST method and it can be accessed in **test.php**

`<?php echo $_GET['testname']; ?>`

with get variable may be also passed via url

`test.php?testname=valueofvariable` it can be accessed with

`<?php echo $_GET['testname']; ?>`

I don't recommend **$_REQUEST** because it handles 3 types of requests which is get, post and cookie and it may cause hard to find errors unless you check what type of request you have via `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`

Comment: Yes I don't want to reload the page and after all the processing in the php page, I have to echo that in the same html page.

Comment: so as I write you have to read some tutorials about ajax, in page I've given you there are a lot of examples how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can access user-provided variables through the `$_REQUEST` array in PHP.

Depending on how you passed the variable (POST or GET request), you can use also `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables.

To show what's inside them you can use [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) function.

Note that `$_REQUEST` will also read user cookies, if there are any.

Comment: e.g., `$_REQUEST['your_url_input_name']`

Comment: Why not use a normal `$_POST` or `$_GET`?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `$_REQUEST` for beginners.

Comment: I put as much effort into the answer as the OP put into researching the question :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="yourPHPPage.php">
<input type="text" name="url"/>
<input type="submit" value="send"/>
</form>
```

PHP :

```
<?php
$url=$_POST['url'];
echo $url;
?>
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could have found this out with little efforts. But here's the basic version:

**your form:**

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
 <p>Link: <input type="text" name="link" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

**action.php:**

```
<?php
$link = $_POST['link'];
echo $link;
?>
```

Check the documentation on creating forms [here](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php).

Hope this helps!